# SQL Azure Data Export Service using C#

Tags: c#, sql, azure, export

I'm new to Azure, I want to know about how we can implement Data Export Service in C#.

Currently I am using windows azure for application development and sql azure for database. So there I want to read the data from my database and update that into some another client database based on a time interval.

I want to implement these function as a windows azure worker role. How can I do this?

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're exactly trying to do but depending on your needs you could use one of the following options:

**SQL DAC**

This is more an import/export like approach (is this what you mean with "Data Export Service"?)

[image]

http://sqldacexamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Import%20Export%20Service%20Client&referringTitle=Documentation

**SQL Azure Data Sync**

This is a synchronization solution, allowing you to use sync groups, filters, specific tables/columns, ... to synchronize data between multiple databases (both SQL Server and SQL Azure are supported).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456371.aspx

Comment: My actual problem is "I am using C#.net to implement some web services and also use SQL azure as database for that services. So there each day i want to check whether there is any updation in my database. If there is an updation then i want to read only that updated data from my sql azure database and load that datainto some another sql database(both SQL Server and SQL Azure)". So i want to implement this function as windows azure worker role. So each and every day these worker role be executed. How i can implement that entire operation using c#

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Sandrino, you can use SQL Azure Data Sync. It supports the features you want to implement. Using an existing product is usually much easier than write your own.

If you want to write your own, please distinguish which data has been modified. You can take the same route as Data Sync does: Create triggers in the database. Whenever a data is inserted, updated, deleted, the trigger is invoked, and you insert some metadata in a tracking table. Then your worker role code queries the tracking table to figure out what data needs to be synched.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog post about this which uses some straightforward tooling to achieve a simple export and import, using task scheduler than worker-role which makes it pretty easy:

https://iainhunter.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/sql-azure-disaster-recovery/